# Using Google cloud vison to recognize Japanese is different twice

Tags: google-cloud-vision

On June 13 and June 30, the same image and character were recognized twice, but the results were different. Has there been any change in the mechanism of Google cloud vision recently?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obWAf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the nature of OCR is that when one part of the recognition is improved, it can affect the recognition of other characters.

Google Cloud Vision's machine learning is updated pretty regularly. If you have an issue with it, they may be able to help you if you contact them.